# WPF ContextMenu with bound items: Items.Count == 0 in ContextMenuOpening event

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listview, contextmenu

I have a `ContextMenu` with the `ItemsSource` bound to the selected item of a list view, like this:

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource possibleConverter}}"/>
```

The `possibleConverter` enumerates all possible values for a property of the the selected item, which are shown in the context menu. In the `Opened` event of the context menu, I select the current value like this:

```
var cm = e.OriginalSource as ContextMenu;
if (cm != null) {
    var lv = cm.PlacementTarget as ListView;
    var field = lv.SelectedItem as Field;
    var item = cm.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(cm.Items.OfType<object>().Where(o => o.ToString().Equals(field.StringValue)).FirstOrDefault()) as MenuItem;
    if (item != null) {
        item.IsChecked = true;
    }
}
```

Not particularly elegant, but it works. With the debugger I verified that the `ContextMenu.Items.Count` property has a non-zero value when expected (i.e. `cm.Items.Count` is non-zero in the if).

So far, so good. There are, however, items in the listview where the context menu will have no items. In this case, an empty menu is shown. I tried to suppress this in the `ContextMenuOpening` event in the list view, like this:

```
var lv = sender as ListView;
if (lv != null) {
    var cm = lv.ContextMenu;
    if ((cm != null) && (cm.Items.Count > 0)) {
        // Here we want to check the current item, which is currently done in the Opened event.
    } else {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Seems like it should work. However, `cm.Items.Count` is always zero. This is true even if `ListView.SelectedItem` did not change: For an item with menu entries, the menu is shown correctly after the first click, so the data binding has already happend. It is shown correct the second time as well, but in any case, `Items.Count` is zero in the `ContextMenuOpening` event.

What am I missing? How can I suppress empty context menus? Why is the count zero in the `ContextMenuOpening` handler, which is in Windows Forms `(ContextMenuStrip.Opening`) the canonical point where to do these things?

EDIT: Upon further investigating, it turns out that in the `ContextMenuOpening` handler, any binding to the listview fails, which is why ItemsSource is null. I tried to bind via `ElementName`, via a `FindAncestor` relationship, all to no avail. The `PlacementTarget` is null during that event. An ugly hack worked though: In the `ContextMenuOpening` event, I assign the list view to the `ContextMenu.Tag` property, while the `ItemsSource` binding now binds to `Tag.SelectedItem`. This updates the binding, so `Items.Count` is what it should be. It's still strange. How can you do meaningful things in `ContextMenuOpening` other than replacing the menu or something, if the binding fails because somehow the context menu is out of context during the event? Was it only tested with static pre-defined menu items?

Comment: Why dont you handle it in the selectedItem property? Bind a property to the selecteditem, and when it changes check if it has any possible items? Then in the opening event you can disable the menu if the check failed